# PlatformException(invalid_source, Invalid image source., null, null) in flutter image_picker: ^0.8.6 Flutter 3.7.10

Tags: android, ios, flutter

PlatformException(invalid_source, Invalid image source., null, null) in flutter  image_picker: ^0.8.6 error while picking image

```
void _getFromCamera(var comp) async {
    comp.pickedFile = await ImagePicker()
        .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, maxHeight: 500, maxWidth: 500);
    setState(() {
      if (comp.pickedFile != null) {
        imageFile?.add(comp.pickedFile);
        fullImage.add(comp.pickedFile.path);
        imageFfile = File(comp.pickedFile.path);

        image = XFile(comp.pickedFile.path);
        confirmImage();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Probably it's emulator bug.

Comment: i try another emulator also same thing